# How to make Mathematica simplify $\cos[(i + j + k)\pi]$ to $(-1)^{i+j+k}$?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, trigonometry

We know that:
$$
\cos\left[(i+j+k)\pi\right] = (-1)^{i+j+k}
$$
for $i, j, k$ being positive integers. In *Mathematica* I've tried:

```
FullSimplify[Cos[(i + j + k)*Pi], Assumptions -> Element[{i, j, k}, {Positive, Integers}]]
```

But it still returns the `Cos` function. Does anyone know how to perform this simplification?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's another way:

```
 Assuming[Element[{i, j, k}, Integers], Refine[Cos[(i + j + k) Pi]]]
```

[image]

Comment: It can be shorter: `Refine[Cos[(i + j + k) Pi], Element[{i, j, k}, Integers]]`

Comment: @Kuba. Indeed. Thanks

Comment: @RunnyKine So... Refine can simplify better than FullSimplify in this case?

Comment: @SaulloCastro. It would seem so since `FullSimplify` is more general than `Refine` and it seems `Refine` is best suited for this situation.

Answer (score 9):

```
FullSimplify[Cos[(i + j + k)*Pi], 
 Assumptions -> Element[i + j + k, Integers], ComplexityFunction -> LeafCount]
```

> (-1)^(i + j + k)

```
Simplify[Cos[t*Pi], Element[t, Integers]] /. t :> i + j + k
```

> (-1)^(i + j + k)

Answer (score 4):

`Element` is not `Listable`, also, `Positive` is not valid domain so it is reasonable to me that it is not working.

If you put the assumptions more carefully then everything is alright:

```
 Simplify[Cos[(i + j + k)*Pi], 
         Element[{i, j, k}, Integers] && And @@ (# > 0 & /@ {i, j, k}), 
         ComplexityFunction -> LeafCount]
```

> $(-1)^{i+j+k}$

Comment: Thank you... you mean that when I do `Element[{i, j, k}, Integers]` it is not applying the assumptions for all the variables?

Comment: @SaulloCastro This should work but using multiple domains shouldn't.

Comment: The ComplexityFunction option is very useful in this situation to determine the rule for ranking the most simplified

Answer (score 2):

Another way is basically use the Mathematica's build in Head for all expressions. The following may seem less elegant but works for arbitrary number of summands:

```
Cos[(intp[a]+intp[b]+intp[c]+intp[d])*Pi]/.Cos[(Plus[x__])*Pi]:>Hold[-1^x]
/;SameQ@@((Head/@List@@x)~Join~{intp})

(* Hold[-1^(int[a]+int[b]+int[c]+int[d])] *)
```

where `intp` is positive integer.

Comment: man... this is hard core stuff...

Comment: This technique is usually good for create data type. Too brutal for this case.