# Why Refine does not simplify Cos[2*Pi*FractionalPart[1/2*(i + j + k)]] to $(-1)^{i+j+k}$?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, trigonometry, conditional

I am obtaining in Mathematica:

```
Cos[2*Pi*FractionalPart[1/2*(i + j + k)]]
```

We know that for $i, j, k$ being positive integers this expression after simplification should give:

$$
(-1)^{i+j+k}
$$

I would like to know why the one of the solutions proposed [for this similar question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/37521/6126):

```
 Refine[Cos[2*Pi*FractionalPart[1/2*(i + j + k)]], 
    Assumptions -> {Element[{i, j, k}, Integers], i > 0, j > 0, k > 0}]
```

did not work for this case?

Comment: @Kuba sorry, that was a copy paste issue from the real code.. I fixed now...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make Mathematica simplify `Cos[(i + j + k) Pi]` to `(-1)^(i+j+k)`?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/37521/how-to-make-mathematica-simplify-cosi-j-k-pi-to-1ijk)

Comment: @Artes this is not a duplicate because the question is asking why the Refine is not working in this case, while the other question was asking how to simplify the expression...

Comment: @Artes I think that it is not a duplicate since `Refine/FullSimplify` works bad with `FractionalPart`.

Comment: @ybeltukov I would retract my close vote if you provided at least a bit more optimal approach e.g. `Simplify[Cos[
  2 Pi (# - Floor@#)&[(i + j + k)/2]], (i | j | k) ∈ 
  Integers]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One can use `x-Floor[x]` instead of `FractionalPart[x]` for positive `x`

```
FullSimplify[Cos[2 Pi ((i + j + k)/2 - Floor[(i + j + k)/2])], 
   Assumptions -> (i | j | k) ∈ Integers]
```

> (-1)^(i + j + k)

Comment: ybeltukov, you haven't been active on this site recently.  I want to let you know that your contributions are missed.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I'm sorry that I have no spare time to participate on this site now. I hope I'll be back in September or earlier. I was glad to talk with Leonid at the recent Wolfram conference in St. Petersburg.

Answer (score 2):

Using the solution proposed in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/37522/6126) also works:

```
FullSimplify[Cos[2 Pi FractionalPart[1/2 (i + j + k)]], 
             Assumptions -> {Element[i + j + k, Integers], i > 0, j > 0, k > 0},
             ComplexityFunction -> LeafCount]
```

Giving:

> (-1)^(i + j + k)